# Unity3d: How to record gameplay video without audio for android device

Tags: unity-game-engine

For android device how to record game play video without audio?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for creating videos as a developer, you can record videos as you would any normal android app by using ADB. ADB is a tool that is included with the Android SDK.

An example command would be

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

This records a video without audio to your sd card in the demo.mp4 file

More details can be found here, https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#screenrecord

Comment: Thanks for your response but i want to record video without audio by using unity3d.